# Changing number to bigger than 999 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes, precision

In QGIS 3.28 on Windows, there is a shapefile originally created in QGIS that was imported and worked on in ArcGIS.

Now, when I reopen the file in QGIS, the real numbers have a width of 18 instead of 23 while the precision is unchanged at 15. However, now it is not possible to change the numbers to a number bigger than 999, even though, the fields are numbers bigger than it.

I will post images later, however, maybe somebody already has an idea of what happened and how I can edit those numbers again.

Comment: The dBase implementation used by ArcGIS uses characters in the `.dbf`, so it's not just the width but also the number of decimal digits that matter. Please [Edit] the Question to provide exact details on the field definition (width and places of precision).

Comment: I edited the question, the precision is unchanged at 15.

Comment: I'll have to go back and look at my dBase support code, but I think the buffer is only 18-20 characters wide. Double precision floats only carry 15-16 digits anyway, so you have noise in the last few digits at 18 width, much less 23.

Comment: Please advice how to create such shapefile with QGIS and what to do with ArcGIS for reproducing the error.